# Way too much oil, loss of power when accelerating & smoke pouring from under the hood?

Tags: engine, oil-change, smoke, oil-seal, power-loss

I picked up my 2013 Ford Escape SEL last night after an oil change/tire rotation, etc. I made it about 10 miles, I pushed the accelerator to travel up a small incline & nothing happened, tried again & it bogged down. Then I noticed smoked rolling from under the hood & quickly pulled over & shut the car off.  A passerby stopped as he thought the car was on fire due to the amount of smoke. As I was pulling over I checked the temp & it was not overheated.  The car was towed back to the dealership that did the service.  The passerby that came to help checked the oil a couple times & it showed WAY above full (WAY= 2 inches above).

I am waiting for the dealership to give me a call back with the verdict.  Any ideas on how screwed my car will be?